# How to read large number of records from SQL table in batches using Task Parallel library

Tags: c#, sql, multithreading, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library

I have a sql table called **Accounts** in SQL server where data is sorted with respect to date. The table has 20 columns including `AccountId`.
I want to read the records for each day (**Around 200K records**). This way I would have to read the data of 6 months for each day.

What I need to do is to fetch records from Accounts Table for 6 Months of data. So I planned my code to get the data from SQL Server `Accounts` table inside a do while loop for each day.

Now, each day consists of fetching 200K records from the database. So I break this 200K records for one day into batches (let's say 10000 or 20000 records in one read which makes around 10 batches of records for one day). Once I get these 10k or 20k records I want to get those values fetched from database and convert the same into a csv file and export the csv file to a location.

Now, my problem is that this procedure is taking too much time (Around 50 minutes for fetching records for one day and I need to fetch the records for 6 months of data. So you can imagine how much time it will take).

I am thinking to make use of TPL to break the code and processing into tasks but not sure how to go about it.

Please suggest how do I make use of Task parallel library to enhance the performance so that I can easily get 6 months of data.

My C# code looks like below:

```
public void Main()
{
    do
    {
        done = true;
        var accountsTableRecors = ReadsDatabaseForADay(lastId);
        foreach (var accountsHistory in accountsTableRecors)
        {
            if (accountsHistory.accountsId != null) lastId = (long)accountsHistory.accountsId;
            done = false;
            recordCount++;
        }
        var flatFileDataList = ProcessRecords();
    } while (!done);
}
```

The `ProcessRecords` method above in `Main()` parses some xml and converts to fetched data into csv.

```
private IEnumerable<AccountsTable> ReadsDatabaseForADay(long lastId)
{
    var transactionDataRecords = DatabaseHelper.GetTransactions(lastId, 10000);
    var accountsTableData = transactionDataRecords as IList<AccountsTable> ?? transactionDataRecords.ToList();
    ListAccountsTable.AddRange(accountsTableData);
    return accountsTableData;
}
```

`DatabaseHelperClass`:

```
internal static IEnumerable<AccountsTable> GetTransactions(long lastTransactionId, int count)
{
    const string sql = "SELECT TOP(@count) [accounts_id],[some_columns],[some_other_columns]. .....[all_other_columns] " 
                    + "FROM AccountsTable WHERE [accounts_id] > @LastTransactionId AND [creation_dt] > DATEADD(DAY,-1, GETDATE())" +
                   " ORDER BY [accounts_id]";
    return GetData(connection =>
    {
        var command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@count", count);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastTransactionId", lastTransactionId);
        return command;
    }, DataRecordToTransactionHistory);
}

private static IEnumerable<T> GetData<T>(Func<SqlConnection, SqlCommand> commandBuilder, Func<IDataRecord, T> dataFunc)
{
    using (var connection = GetOpenConnection())
    {
        using (var command = commandBuilder(connection))
        {
            command.CommandTimeout = 0;
            using (IDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    var record = dataFunc(reader);
                    yield return record;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't you do this with something like SSIS instead of code? Using tasks might not solve the problem since you might overload the server. Have you gone to the bottom to see if the queries are optimized using indexes etc. Or can you approach the export to CSV in a whole other way?

Comment: Sure I should Peter, but here the problem is two fold. The data resides on production server to which I do not have direct access and secondly, there are lot of columns which needs data manipulation after fetching. Hence, I chose the code way

Comment: Fetching 200k rows should take seconds not an hour so you need to fix that problem before you start throwing TPL at it.

Answer (score 2):

Your code has some issues into it, which may lead to poor performance. First of all, you're creating a list from `IEnumerable` each time you get another batch of account tables. `List<T>` uses an array internally, which goes to large object heap by default, and that heap doesn't GC'ed frequently, so by time you'll got a memory issues and performance drawback.

Second issue is that your code is highly I/O oriented, but you do not use the `async` methods, so your thread will be blocked by waiting the database to respond. You should switch to `async` version and use the blocking methods only inside the `Main` entrance point, but in this case you wouldn't be able to `yield` your results, as `async Task<IEnumerable>` can't be an iterator, and you need to edit your `DataRecordToTransactionHistory` function or create a list locally inside your `GetData` function:

```
private static async Task GetData(Func<SqlConnection, SqlCommand> commandBuilder,
    Action<IDataRecord> dataFunc)
{
    using (var connection = new SqlConnection())
    {
        await connection.OpenAsync();
        using (var command = commandBuilder(connection))
        {
            command.CommandTimeout = 0;
            using (var reader = await command.ExecuteReaderAsync())
            {
                while (await reader.ReadAsync())
                {
                    dataFunc(reader);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
// OR
private static async Task<IEnumerable<T>> GetData<T>(Func<SqlConnection, SqlCommand> commandBuilder,
    Func<IDataRecord, T> dataFunc)
{
    using (var connection = new SqlConnection())
    {
        await connection.OpenAsync();
        using (var command = commandBuilder(connection))
        {
            command.CommandTimeout = 0;
            using (var reader = await command.ExecuteReaderAsync())
            {
                // linked list to avoid allocation of an array
                var result = new LinkedList<T>();
                while (await reader.ReadAsync())
                {
                    result.AddLast(dataFunc(reader));
                }
                return result;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, both of these options have their disadvantages. As for me, you should give a try to the [`TPL Dataflow`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228603.aspx) library with processing pipeline like this:

```
// default linking options
var options = new DataflowLinkOptions { PropagateCompletion = true };

// store all the ids you need to process
var idBlock = new BufferBlock<long>();

// transform id to list of AccountsTable
var transformBlock = new TransformBlock<long, Task<IEnumerable<AccountsTable>>>(async id =>
{
    return await ReadsDatabaseForADay(id);
});

// connect the blocks between each other
idBlock.LinkTo(transformBlock, options);

// flatten the already completed task to enumerable
var flattenBlock = new TransformManyBlock<Task<IEnumerable<AccountsTable>>, AccountsTable>(async tables =>
{
    return (await tables).Select(t => t);
});
transformBlock.LinkTo(flattenBlock, options);

// gather results in batches of 10000
var batchBlock = new BatchBlock<AccountsTable>(10000);
flattenBlock.LinkTo(batchBlock);

// export resulting array to csv file
var processor = new ActionBlock<AccountsTable[]>(a =>
{
    ExportToCSV(a);
});

// populate the pipeline with needed ids
foreach (var id in GetAllIds())
{
    // await the adding for each id
    await idBlock.SendAsync(id);
}
// notify the pipeline that all the data has been sent
idBlock.Complete();

// await whole ids to be processed
await processor.Completion;
```

`TPL Dataflow` executes in default thread pool and uses all the advantages of it. You may adjust the blocks [with `MaxDegreeOfParrallelism`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228609.aspx) so it can handle more than one id in at a moment.

So, you should use `async` methods and you shouldn't create too many buffer lists/arrays just for storing the data. Assemble your pipeline to use full advantages of iterators and `async/await` functions.